# COUNT(*) or separate table for keeping track of total?

Tags: mysql, database

Suppose I have a MySQL table of dogs, t_dogs, with columns of owner name, breed, weight, age, etc.  If I knew there are certain count queries that'll be performed frequently such as total number of dogs by an certain owner or age, should I use `COUNT(*) FROM ...  WHERE ...`  or should I create a separate table for keeping track of total number of dogs by owner, age, etc?

The number of updates to total number of dogs for an owner, age is minimal compared to how many times the total number is queried.

Thanks!

Comment: This question would be better asked over on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think creating a separate table for keeping track of total number by certain field is expensive than `COUNT(*) FROM ... WHERE ...`

Comment: Why keep it in a separate table when you can calculate it?  If you have changes to the count, then you need to update the data in the separate table.  If you use `count(*)` then the total is updated when you query it.

Comment: Cache is King. BTW he said nothing about his requirements

Comment: @bluefeet Isn't it expensive to do a `COUNT(*)` based on a query?  While a retrieval from a separate count table is much faster?  I realize there's an incurred cost with updating total, but that's far less frequent than actual queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a separate table is denormalised design, but it might be justified if not doing it would significantly impact performance. If you do choose to do this, then it becomes your job to keep the table of metadata updated properly, which is an additional burden and set of things that can go wrong.

For MySQL it matters what storage engine you are using. InnoDB performs poorly with COUNT(*) queries IIRC. For MyISAM it does not matter so much.

Comment: MyISAM is super fast only for queries of the type: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BaseTable ;` without `WHERE`, without `GROUP BY`. For any other slightly more complex counting, performance is comparable if not worse than InnoDB.

Comment: @Luke Keeping your database normalized and having **one** point of maintenance is far more important then worrying about the speed of your queries. Only when your database runs into the millions of records you might want to think about your 'separate table' idea.